# Sitecore placeholder is not visible on experience editor

Tags: experience-editor

I have applied a few placeholders in view rendering and also created a placeholder in placeholder setting in Sitecore. In placeholder settings `Editable` is true but placeholder is not getting visible on experience editor. When I go to the particular placeholder and `uncheck Editable checkbox` and again `check Editable checkbox` then it started visibly but after some time I face the again same issue. Please help.

Comment: Downvoted, as your question is about the visibility/non-visibility of a placeholder in EE - not about certain components not showing up when inserting into the (visible) placeholder. Question could do with a clarification, to match the self-answer you indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this issue by updating below setting

```
 <setting name="Query.MaxItems">  <patch:attribute name="value">1000</patch:attribute></setting>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but out of curiosity, What is the relation between this setting and placeholder setting?

Comment: This worked for me too, the interesting thing is that I put it back to 100 and still works. I think that it must have been cached somewhere and when I changed the config Sitecore restarted and cleared the cache. cause honestly I went back to 100 and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question you can check in the following areas to see why it is not shown.

1. Check to see if you are on experience editor mode when you do not see the placeholder.
2. are there allowed renderings added to the placeholder you want to edit.
3. debug the pipeline if there are any pipelines(like getPlaceholderrenderings) which are calculating computed renderings on the FYI.

Comment: Yes I have allowed rendering in placeholder but I can not see placeholder, as I mentioned above when I untick and tick editable checkbox it is started displaying. I have not created any pipeline